# XML: MSXML Not Installed

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing

Using this code to get rss of a site. This code works fine for my computer and many other computers. But in some computers (Windows XP or 7) I get this error: **MSXML Not Installed**

**How can I fix this problem? What is wrong?**

Here is the code:

```
procedure My_Thread.Execute;
var
  http                 : tidhttp;
  strm                 : tmemorystream;
  str,sTitle,  sDec ,er : string;
  StartItemNode        : IXMLNode;
  ANode                : IXMLNode;
  XMLDoc               : IXMLDocument;

begin
  http := tidhttp.Create();
  strm := tmemorystream.Create;
    try
      http.Get('http://www.sample.com/rss.xml',strm);     //Download the RSS file
      SetString(str,PANSIChar(strm.Memory),strm.Size);

      XMLDoc :=  LoadXMLData(str);

      StartItemNode := XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('item');
      ANode         := StartItemNode;

      i := 0;
      repeat
        inc(i);
        sTitle    := ANode.ChildNodes['title'].Text;
        sDec       := ANode.ChildNodes['description'].Text;
        Synchronize(procedure begin            //Synchronize? I'm using threads
          case I of
            1: begin
                 main_frm.edit1.text := sTitle; //main_frm is my form
                 main_frm.edit2.text := sDec;
               end;
            2: begin
                 main_frm.edit3.text := sTitle;
                 main_frm.edit4.text := sDec;
               end;
            3: begin
                 main_frm.edit5.text := sTitle;
                 main_frm.edit6.text := sDec;
               end;
          end;
          ANode := ANode.NextSibling;
        end);
      until ANode = nil;

      http.Free;
      strm.Free;

    except
      on E: Exception do
        begin
          er := e.Message;
          Synchronize(procedure begin
            ShowMessage(er);
          end);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

As you see I'm useing threads. So `Synchronize` was needed.

Comment: You get that message from an exception, right? The debugger interrupts your program and tells you exactly where the exception came from, doesn't it? So debug it. At the very least, include the source of the exception in your question.

Comment: This is a complete aside, but `Dec` is a function (in unit `System`) that is used to decrement an integer.  Here you declare a string variable `Dec`, which hides that function.  This is bad practice, especially for such a common function as `dec` - you should use a unique name for your variables.

Comment: @RobKennedy No. On my system the code works fine. I cannot debug it on another computer. So I used `ShowMessage(er);` But I think the error is because of `XMLDoc :=  LoadXMLData(str);`. I used `TXMLDocument` (added it on the main form) instead of `XMLDoc : IXMLDocument;` and also removed the thread. It worked on all computers. Don't know why.

Comment: I'd think you'd need to call 'CoInitializeEx' in the thread before using MSXML. But working on some computers.., dunno..

Comment: ShowMessage isn't a remote debugging tool. Use MadExcept to collect real exception information. Don't *catch* an exception unless you know how to resolve the problem that triggered it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On Windows, `TXMLDocument` uses MSXML by default, which uses COM objects.  Your thread is not calling `CoInitialize/Ex()` before loading the XML, so COM is not able to instantiate any of the MSXML COM objects that `IXMLDocument` attempts to create internally (it attempts to create multiple COM objects to discover which version of MSXML is actually installed).  The error message you are seeing means all of the MSXML COM objects failed to instantiate.

You MUST call `CoInitialize/Ex()` in every thread context that accesses COM objects, eg:

```
procedure My_Thread.Execute;
var
  ...
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    ...
    XMLDoc := LoadXMLData(str);
    try
     ...
    finally
      // Since CoInitialize() and CoUninitialize() are being called in the same
      // method as local COM interface variables, it is very important to release
      // the COM interfaces before calling CoUninitialize(), do not just let them
      // release automatically when they go out of scope, as that will be too late...
      StartItemNode := nil;
      ANode := nil;
      XMLDoc := nil;
    end;
    ...
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

**UPDATE**: If you don't want to rely on this: you can use a different XML library of your choosing, you don't have to use MSXML:

[Using the Document Object Model](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_Document_Object_Model)

> Selecting an XML Vendor
>
> When you build an application, RAD Studio uses the default built-in XML vendor, **MSXML**.
>
> If you do not specify a different XML vendor, your application does not have XML support on other platforms than Windows, and you see a run-time exception when you run your application in other platforms. For cross-platform applications, **OmniXML** is currently the best choice, as it shows much better performance than **ADOM**.
>
> To choose a different XML vendor, [add a reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Adding_a_Unit_Reference) to the unit of the vendor into the unit where you use the RTL XML features, such as the [`TXMLDocument`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument) class. If you add more than one XML vendor unit, the first unit referenced is used as XML vendor. If you need to override this behavior, change the value of the [`DefaultDOMVendor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.xmldom.DefaultDOMVendor) global variable to the global variable of the XML vendor that you want to use.
>
> Note: You can look up the unit and the global variable of each XML vendor in the [List of Built-in XML Vendors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_Document_Object_Model#List_of_Built-in_XML_Vendors) above.
>
> When you use the [`TXMLDocument`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument) component, you can choose an XML vendor using its [`DOMVendor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.DOMVendor) property. When you change the value of [`DOMVendor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.DOMVendor), the unit that uses the component is configured to use the specified XML vendor, so that you do not need to change unit references or the [`DefaultDOMVendor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.xmldom.DefaultDOMVendor) global variable manually.

Comment: That comment about releasing the COM interfaces is really interesting. Does this also apply to interfaces generated by importing WSDL?

Comment: @LucasSteffen It applies only to interfaces used with COM objects specifically. Delphi interfaces in general are not dependent on COM (though Delphi's `IInterface` is modeled after COM's `IUnknown`). AFAIK, Delphi's WSDL framework is not based on COM.

Comment: Why doesn't anyone share the units required in the uses clause for what is in their code???

Answer (score 1):

MSXMLS needs to be installed before.. in servicePack2 for XP MSXML 4.0 Service Pack 2 (Microsoft XML Core Services) 
Microsoft Core XML Services (MSXML) 6.0 the same for windows 7..
Bye

Comment: But when I use `TXMLDocument` in form without using thread it works fine. Why?

Comment: Maybe they are not threadsafe. You showld take care of that doing a critical section maybe.. Is it really need to use threads for that? I think you have the data in memory it is just need to put it into the form! bye

Comment: I removed the thread. It worked. But I need to use it in threads :(

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem in one of my Delphi projects, but I used IdThreadComponent instead of Thread object. my problem was at line:
DOC:= NewXMLDocument;
I remove this line from inside the thread run method and bring it right before the calling Thread as below:
Doc := NewXMLDocument;
IdThreadComponent1.Start;

Comment: After that i saw a same problem again. The new problem happened when I call a procedure to save my xml file. Finally I solved that with this line: IdThreadComponent1.Synchronize(SaveXML);

Comment: That is because you are creating the XMLDocument in the main UI thread, so only that thread can use it by default. MSXML's COM objects do not use a multi-threaded apartment model, so you would have to manually marshal its COM interface across thread boundaries. Best to just create the XMLDocument in the same thread that will be using it.  Just make sure to initialize the COM library in that thread beforehand